# Use actionButton with updateSelectInput in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I Have a shiny app that use UpdateselectInput, I want to add a actionButton because there are some bugs whis the updateselectInput alone.
It doesnt seem to work, I want to show the table only if I action the button
My app is similar to this one :

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", LETTERS)),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1)))),
                 selectInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", letters)),
                 actionButton("go_button", "GO !")),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$go_button
    # Data
    df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
                 letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

    df1 <- df

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter1)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)



    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }
    datatable(df1)

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Not quite sure what you are looking for. Do you want to add a new `actionButton` and show the table only when you click on the button? Also what is wrong with the `updateSelectInput`?

Comment: Yes I want to show my table only if I click on the button. But in my example, the table appears automaticly ...
My real data is quite big and when I filter it some bugs appears when I try to change modalities in variable filters, the app stuck and I have to close it for fixing the problem. I think an action button could do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?? Only when you click on the `Go` button, will the table display now. The way the filters work are just the same.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", LETTERS)),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1)))),
                 selectInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", letters)),
                 actionButton("go_button", "GO !")),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  goButton <- eventReactive(input$go_button,{
    # Data
    df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
                 letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

    df1 <- df

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter1)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)



    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }
    datatable(df1)
  })

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
    goButton()

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have moved the filter code to a `eventReactive` function. So when you click on the button, it will subset your data based on the filters. And the `output$tableprint` function calls this reactive function, so you will see the table only when you click on the button.

Comment: Thank you very much but I want to keep the `updateselectinput()` function to update my filters, for example I want to show only 1 and 27 in filter 2 choice if I choose A in first filter